# A start job is running for Wait For Network to be Configured because IPv6 blocked

Tags: networking, 22.04, ipv6, systemd-networkd

I have some freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 servers. One is already running 22.04.1, just installed today.

All of them are having the issue that "A start job is running for Wait For Network to be Configured" is hanging at boot for 2 minutes.

The network configuration is trivial, here is one from one of the servers in `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.5.20/24
      gateway4: 192.168.5.2
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        search: []
  version: 2
```

The output for `systemctl show -p WantedBy network-online.target` is:

```
WantedBy=cloud-final.service cloud-config.service open-iscsi.service iscsid.service
```

I haven't been able to identify via the syslog or dmesg which service or which interface (there is only one) is causing the issue.

How can I troubleshoot this? Is it a bug in 22.04?

## Update

I have figured out that the problem is due to the fact that we are completely blocking IPv6 on our servers via `iptables` like so:

```
sudo ip6tables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  623 43589 ACCEPT     all      lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 REJECT     all      any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  623 43589 ACCEPT     all      any    lo      anywhere             anywhere
   92  5504 REJECT     all      any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
```

I have found this issue on Github that discusses this: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2713
But it seems like there is no real solution?

Comment: "This is the network config written by 'subiquity'" I respectfully disagree with subiquiy's work here. I suggest that you conform the file to the template found in: `/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml`

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` times out. This can be reproduced by running the following command on the host:

```
sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online
```

It will never finish.

---

You can also see with `networkctl` that the interface is not properly configured:

```
$ networkctl
IDX LINK  TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo    loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 ens33 ether    routable    unconfigured       <--- should be "configured"
```

Since this seems to be related to the firewall, it is likely because the interface cannot send any IPv6 autoconf messages and is therefore never considered to be properly configured.

---

You can solve this by (1) either removing any link-local address in your netplan config like so:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.5.20/24
      gateway4: 192.168.5.2
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        search: []
      link-local: []     <- IPv6 usually has a default link-local address, we override this
  version: 2
```

(2) enabling autoconf packets in your firewall to leave the host, or

(3) disable autoconf for the interface https://superuser.com/questions/33196/how-to-disable-autoconfiguration-on-ipv6-in-linux

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

In the `[Service]` block:

From

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

To

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutStartSec=2sec
```

Then reboot, you can get the verification.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I can easily solve this by disabling the following services:

```
sudo systemctl disable cloud-init.service cloud-final.service
```

I don't need them when I have configured a static IP.
I assume that also DHCP doesn't need `cloud-init`, I'll test this.

### UPDATE

This actually does not work. I made a mistake in my initial test.
I.e. disabling the services does not help, the 2 minute hang still happens.

Furthermore, I mixed up `cloud-init` and `cloud-config`.
I also tried to disable `cloud-config`, but this also didn't help. It caused other errors to show up during boot though.

I tried disabling IPv6 completely via `sysctl.conf` as shown here: https://itsfoss.com/disable-ipv6-ubuntu-linux/
But it didn't help either.

So I am pretty lost and hope somebody here in the forum has an advice?